# como puedo ordenar fechas por año?

Tags: javascript, html, vuetify

Tengo una tabla con fechas y las quiero ordenar por año, pero cuando les doy ordenar por fecha las ordena por día, ¿cómo puedo arreglarlo?

A los datos los obtengo por una API , los introduzco en la tabla por el método push, pero los ordena por día, si tengo por ejemplo `20/02/2020` , está primero que `31/07/2021` y debería ordenarse por año en vez del primer dato que es el día

Mi codigo HTML:

```html
<v-data-table
            :sort-by="['fecha']"
            :sort-desc="[true]"
            dense
            :headers="ListasPrecios"
            :items  ="contenidoListasPrecios"
            hide-default-footer
            :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
            >
</v-data-table>
```

JavaScript:

```javascript
let fecha = moment(this.fechaAltaListaPrecios).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
console.log('let fecha: ' + fecha);
console.log(this.descripcionListaPrecios.length);
console.log(this.descripcionListaPrecios)  ;
this.listaPreciosAInsertar = {
            descripcion: this.descripcionListaPrecios,
            version: this.versionVigente,
            fecha: fecha       
};
this.contenidoListasPrecios.push(this.listaPreciosAInsertar);
```

Comment: Y si en vez de usar el formato DD/MM/YYYY, usas el YYYY/MM/DD?

Comment: ingresándolo así lo ordena bien pero la idea es mostrarle al usuario el formato DD/MM/YYYY para que se vea mejor

Comment: Por favor comparte la función que ordena las fechas, asi podemos ayudarte

Comment: @AndresGardiol lo ordeno con las propiedades de la tabla vuetify :sort-by="'fecha']"
   y  :sort-desc="[true]"

Answer (score 0):

cuando yo requiero ordenar una tabla suelo anexar una variable de ordenamiento ejemplo JSON:

```
  items: [
    {
      descripcion: "dasdad",
      version: "dasd",
      fecha: "20/02/2018",
      año: "3000"
    },
    {
      descripcion: "dasdad",
      version: "dasd",
      fecha: "20/02/2020",
      año: "2020"
    }]
```

Y utilizo esa variable para ordenarla:

```
<v-data-table
      :sort-by="['año']"
      :sort-desc="[true]"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    ></v-data-table>
```